# Given k is a natural number. Find all functions $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} $ satisfy this

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

This function need to satisfy $f(m)+f(n)$ is divisor of $(m+n)^k,$ with $m,n$ are natural numbers. In this problem, $\mathbb N$ does not include $0.$

In the case k=1, I managed to solve this by replacing $m$ and $n$ with 1;p-1;p (p is prime number) and received $f(n)=n.$ For other $k,$ I have no idea.

Comment: $k\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes k is a natural number and k can’t be 0

Comment: The first thing that occurs to me is to set $m=n$ and get $f(n)\mid 2^{k-1}n^k.$ Also, if $\gcd(m,n)=1,$ then $\gcd(f(n),f(m))=1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How did you get $gcd(m,n)=1 \implies gcd(f(m),f(n))=1$? If that's true, we have $f(n) | n^k$...

Comment: I might have jumped the gun on the gcd part.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the $k = 1$ case? I agree that $f(p-1) = p-1$ for prime $p$. How did you show that $f(n) = n$ for general $n$?

Comment: @Calvin note that for a fixed $m$ and any prime $p$ one has $p-1<f(m)+p-1$ divides $p-1+m$ so in particular if $p$ is large so $\frac{p-1+m}{p-1}<2$, one must have $f(m)+p-1=p-1+m$ hence $f(m)=m$

Comment: @Conrad Yes I was aware of that. It was pointing out to OP that his stated approach needs more details to be complete.

Comment: @Calvin - sorry for misreading the comment but I thought the op implied that even if it wasn't spelled out;

Answer (score 2):

We will show that $f(n)=n$ is the only solution for any $k \ge 2$ too. First we note that $f(1),f(2)$ are powers of two but their sum divides $3^k$ so is odd, hence either $f(1)=1$ or $f(2)=1$. We will first treat $f(1)=1$ and show that $f(m)=m$ and then show the second case is impossible

So assume $f(1)=1$ and then $f(2)=2^a, 1 \le a \le 2k$ is even, hence for any odd $m$ we have $2^a+f(m)$ divides $(m+2)^k$ odd, hence $f(m)$ odd, so in particular since $f(m)$ divides $2^km^k$ it follows $f(m)$ divides $m^k$ so $f(p)=p^{a(p)}, 0 \le a(p) \le k$ for any odd prime $p$

Fix a prime $p$ and assume $f(p)=p^a, a \le k, a \ne 1$. Let $q$ an arbitrary large prime and note that $2 \le f(q-p)+f(p)$ divides $q^k$ so $f(q-p)=q^b-p^a$ for some $1 \le b=b(q) \le k$.

Let $P$ the set of odd primes (they include $p$) that divide any of $p^y-p^x, 0 \le x < y \le k$ or divide $a$ above and if $p=3, k=2$ we add $5$ to the set so it contains at least one odd prime that is not $p$ (since the set contains always the prime divisors of $p-1, p+1$ as $k \ge 2$, one of those is not divisible by $4$ so has an odd  prime factor not $p$ unless of course $p-1=2, k=2$) and let $t=4\Pi_{x \in P}=4pQ$ where $Q=q_1..q_s \ge 3$ the product of the odd primes distinct from $p$ which are in $P$.

Let $c=\frac{Q+1}{2}$, so $(cp, Q)=1$ and hence by Dirichlet theorem there is a large prime $r$ congruent with $pc$ modulo $Q$ so $(r,Q)=1$ and $2r+p$ congruent with $2p$ modulo $Q$ so $(2r+p, Q)=1$ also hence we now can apply Dirichlet to $4pQk+p+2r$ ($(4p, p+2r)=1$ obviously as $r$ large prime)  and get arbitrarily large primes $q=4pQk+p+2r$ so $q-p$ doesn't divide by $4$ and also $(q-p, pQ)=1$

So $f(q-p)=q^b-p^a$ which divides $2^k(q-p)^k$ (as $f(m)$ divides $(2m)^k$ by hypothesis) cannot divide by a power of $2$ larger than $2^{2k}$ so in particular as $q^b-p^a \to \infty, q \to \infty$, we can actually pick $q$ st $f(q-p)=q^{b(q)}-p^a$ is not a power of two, so there is an odd prime divisor $s$ of it which then divides $q-p$ by the above.

Then $s$ divides $q^b-p^b$ hence $p^b-p^a$ so unless $b=a$ we get $s$ divides $pQ$ (since that contains all the factors of $p^b-p^a$ by the definition of $Q$)  and that is impossible by our choice of $q$.

Now if $b=a \ge 2$, the same reasoning as above ($q^a-p^a$ divides $2^{2k}(2m+1)$ so limiting the powers of two that can divide it and $\frac{q^a-p^a}{q-p} \to \infty, q \to \infty$, so we can choose our $q$ in the arithmetic progression $4pQk+p+2r$ above st $\frac{q^a-p^a}{q-p}$ is not a power of two) means that we can pick an odd prime divisor $s$ of $\frac{q^a-p^a}{q-p}$, so $s$ divides $f(q-p)$ hence as before it divides $q-p$ but then $\frac{q^a-p^a}{q-p}$ is congruent with $ap^a$ modulo $s$ so $s$ must divide $ap$ and that again is impossible by our choice of $q$

Hence $f(p)=p$ for all odd primes $p$

But now if $m$ is any natural number and $p$ is a prime, $f(m)+p$ divides $(m+p)^k=((m-f(m))+(f(m)+p))^k=(m-f(m))^k+c(f(m)+p)$ so $f(m)+p$ divides the fixed number $(m-f(m))^k$ for any prime $p$ which of course implies $f(m)=m$ and we are done with this case!

Edit later (the original solution of this case is incorrect as pointed in the comments but it is still easy to do it) Assume now $f(2)=1$ and $f(1)=2^a,  a\ge1$; but now $f$(odd)+$f$(even) is odd, hence $f$(odd) is even and $f$(even) is odd so in particular $f(2^m)=1$ for all $m \ge 1$ since $f(2^m)$ divides $2^{mk+k}$; but now pick a prime $p$ that divides $f(2^m)+f(1)=2^a+1 \ge 3$, so $p$ divides all $(2^m+1)^k$ hence all $2^m+1, m \ge 1$ so in particular $p$ divides $3$ and $5$ and we get the required contradiction!

Note that one can show that $f(m)=m$ as long as there is a sequence $q_n \to \infty$ st $f(q_n)=q_n$ becuase $f(m)+q_n$ divides then $(f(m)-m)^k$ which is a fixed number

Similarly one can show that there cannot be two distinct numbers $f(a)=f(b)=1$ because then $f(m)+1$ would divide $(m+a)^k, (m+b)^k$ for all $m$ but one can easily find $m$ st $(m+a, m+b)=1$  (eg pick a large enough prime $p$ and take $m=p-a$ as $0<p-a+b<2p$ and $p-a+b \ne p$)

Comment: In the final paragraph, why does $f(p)$ being even mean that it is a power of $2$?

Comment: @S.Dolan you are correct and that part was wrong, but it is very easy to do it still

Answer (score 2):

**An elementary proof that each $f(n)=n$.**

Let $m=n$ then $f(n)|2^{k-1}n^k$. Then, for any $a\ge 0$, there is a $b\ge 0$ such that $f(2^a)=2^b$.

First suppose that $f(2)=f(4)=1$. Then $1+f(1)=f(2)+f(1)$ is a power of $3$  and $1+f(1)=f(4)+f(1)$ is a power of $5$. We therefore have the contradiction that $1+f(1)=1$. Hence $f(2x)$ is even for some $x$.

Let $n$ be odd. Then $f(n)+f(2x)$ is a factor of the odd number $(n+2x)^k$. Hence $f(n)$ is odd and therefore $f(n)|n^k$. In particular, $f(1)=1$.

Let $f(4)=2^A$. Then $1+2^A=f(1)+f(4)$ is a power of $5$, say $5^B$. If $B=2C$, then $2^A=(5^C-1)(5^C+1)$ which is impossible. If $B$ is odd, then $2^A$ has the odd factor $1+5+...+5^{B-1}$ and therefore $B=1$ i.e. $f(4)=4$.

Let $p$ be an odd prime greater than $3$ and congruent to $3$ modulo $4$. Then $1+f(2^p-1)=f(1)+f(2^p-1)$ is a power of $2$, say $2^n$. Therefore  $f(2^p-1)=2^n-1$ is a factor of $(2^p-1)^k$. Let $g=\text{ gcd}(n,p)$.

Any prime factor $q$ of $2^n-1$ is then a factor of $2^g-1$. If $g=1$, then $f(2^p-1)=1$ and, otherwise, $n$ is a multiple of $p$. In the first case,  $5=f(4)+f(2^p-1)$ is not  a factor of $(2^p+3)^k$ and so $n$ is a multiple of $p$. But then $2^n-1$ has a prime factor which is not a factor of $2^p-1$ unless $n=p$. (Bang's Theorem of 1886).

We have thus found an infinite sequence of integers $x_i$ such that $f(x_i)=x_i$ for all $i$. Let $n\in \mathbb N$, then each $f(x_i)+f(n)=x_i+f(n)$ is a factor of $(x_i+n)^k$ and hence of $(f(n)-n)^k$. Therefore $f(n)=n$ and we are finished.